# Boost async_read во время посимвольного чтения из потока перезатрает буфер

Tags: boost, asio

Всем добрый вечер!

Во время написания написания **чат - сервера** с использованием либы **Boost** возникла **проблема чтения данных из потока**.

Функция async_read считывает посимвольно данные в **m_read_buffer** из потока и вызывается функцией **read_complete**. Во время произвольного вызова do_read для чтения данных в буфер из async_read символы начинают перезаписывать буфер.

```
enum { max_msg = 1024 };
char read_buffer_[max_msg];

void do_read() 
{
    async_read(m_sock, buffer(read_buffer_), 
               boost::bind(read_complete,_1,_2),  
               boost::bind(on_read,_1,_2));
}

size_t read_complete(const boost::system::error_code & err, size_t bytes) 
{
    if ( err) return 0;
    bool found = std::find(read_buffer_, read_buffer_ + bytes, '\n') < read_buffer_ + bytes;
    // we read one-by-one until we get to enter, no buffering
    return found ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Рассмотрим пример данных, отправленных от клиента, и будем наблюдать, как изменяется наш буфер все время. Данные от клиента: **"I'm user and want to log in\n"**. На примере видно, что сначала в конец буффера дополняется символ с нечетным индексом, а следующим за ним перезаписывает предыдущий символ. Таким образом, в буффер помещаются символы, стоящие на четных местах в строке данных.

Буфер **m_read_buffer** во время различных итераций разделен запятыми:

**""**, **I**, **'**, **'m**, **' **, **' u**, **' s**, **' se**, **' sr**, **' sr **, **' sra**, **' srn**, **' srnd**, **' srn **, **' srn w**, **' srn a**, **' srn an**, **' srn at**, **' srn at **, **' srn att**, **' srn ato**, **' srn ato **, **' srn atol**, **' srn atolo**, **' srn atolg** , **' srn atolg ** , **' srn atolgi**, **' srn atolgin**, **' srn atolgi\n**.

Answer (score -1):

Вытащи константу из `enum`. Ограничение буфера у тебя 8 символов, а не `1024`.

Comment: Сделал - не помогло ((